# Print commit message of a given commit in git

Tags: git, commit-message

I need a plumbing command to print the commit message of one given commit - nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: If anyone comes here looking for a way to print a single-line commit message but doesn't care about the hash appearing at the beginning, the following works: `git show -s --oneline <commit>`

Comment: Where should we add the line to print the commit message in server machine? I meant which hook file?

Comment: What do you mean by "plumbing" command?

Comment: @BryanAsh https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain

Comment: @BryanAsh from that link: `Plumbing and Porcelain

This book covers primarily how to use Git with 30 or so subcommands such as checkout, branch, remote, and so on. But because Git was initially a toolkit for a version control system rather than a full user-friendly VCS, it has a number of subcommands that do low-level work and were designed to be chained together UNIX-style or called from scripts. These commands are generally referred to as Git’s “plumbing” commands, while the more user-friendly commands are called “porcelain” commands.`

Answer (score 478, accepted):

It's not "plumbing", but it'll do exactly what you want:

```
$ git log --format=%B -n 1 <commit>
```

If you absolutely need a "plumbing" command (not sure why that's a requirement), you can use `rev-list`:

```
$ git rev-list --format=%B --max-count=1 <commit>
```

Although `rev-list` will also print out the commit sha (on the first line) in addition to the commit message.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me - but I used `%s%b` instead of `%B` (on a Linux box)

Comment: `%B` is a correct specifier (at least, in Git 1.7.2, not sure when it was added).

Comment: `%B` was added sometime after 1.7.1 (probably in 1.7.1.1).

Comment: Indeed it is - Git 1.7.2 apparently.  Muchas gracias!

Comment: You can also use:
`$ git log --format=%B -n 1 <commit> | cat -`
That will give you the commit message and no commit sha, and you can "pipe" it. I actually use this as part of my CI script.

Comment: I prefer `%s` instead of `%B` because it prints only the commit message subject, not the body (expanded description) if one is supplied

Comment: If you are using `git log` but specifying the format, surely it's as good as using a plumbing command, no?

Comment: @AndrewSpencer, no extensive testing but `git log` appears slower

Comment: "Although rev-list will also print out the commit sha (on the first line) in addition to the commit message." -> is there a way to suppress this?

Comment: You wouldn't need to pass the commit hash because you are already using `-n 1` flag which gives you the last commit.

Answer (score 197):

`git show` is more a plumbing command than `git log`, and has the same formatting options:

```
git show -s --format=%B SHA1
```

Comment: And if you just want the first line ("subject"), use `%s` instead of `%B`.

Comment: (I prefer this to the accepted "log" or "rev-list" answer, as it's a single-commit operation, rather than a list restricted to 1 entry.)

Comment: @Rich what do you mean by that?

Comment: @CervEd - I mean that the "log" and "rev-list" commands operate on lists of commits, and the other answers here restrict the list to length 1. It's an unnecessary level of indirection and complicates things. The "log" op in git is kind of like doing "`let xs = [123]; for (x in xs) { show(x) }`", but it's simpler and quicker to just do `show(123)`.

Comment: @Rich `git show` is a lot slower than `git rev-list --max-count 1`

Comment: @CervEd:You're right; that's really weird. I don't know why that would be. In my mental model of things, rev-list ought to be slower as it is doing the same work on each element of a list that "show" is doing on a single named commit. Either I misunderstand something or rev-list is optimised in some way that show isn't (but could be, for this case at least).

Comment: I think you're making the assumption that because `rev-list` has a `max-count` option and `show` doesn't that `rev-list` is iterating over the whole tree or doing something computationally intensive. But you can't make such assumptions on the internal workings based on the public API. `git show` is a porcelain command, without having dug deep, I'm assuming it's using the exact same mechanics as `rev-list` as well as a whole bunch of other *user-friendly* operations that slow it down. Porcelain commands are not optimized for speed

Comment: The fact that `git show` needs `--no-pager` kind of shows you it's not a plumbing command.

Answer (score 24):

Not plumbing, but I have these in my .gitconfig:

```
lsum = log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%s'
lmsg = log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%s%n%n%b'
```

That's "last summary" and "last message". You can provide a commit to get the summary or message of that commit. (I'm using 1.7.0.5 so don't have %B.)

Comment: You can pass -n argument as a parameter. So instead of only return last commit you can make it to return last 5 commits. Here the change necessary

 lsum = "!f() { git log -n $1 --pretty=format:'%s'; }; f"
 lmsg = "!f() { git log -n $1 --pretty=format:'%s%n%n%b'; }; f"

Found it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005513/pass-an-argument-to-a-git-alias-command

You just run this git lsum 5

Answer (score 19):

This will give you a very compact list of all messages for any specified time.

```
git log --since=1/11/2011 --until=28/11/2011 --no-merges --format=%B > CHANGELOG.TXT
```

Answer (score 18):

I started to use

```
git show-branch --no-name <hash>
```

It seems to be faster than

```
git show -s --format=%s <hash>
```

Both give the same result

I actually wrote a small tool to see the status of all my repos. You can find it on [github](https://github.com/nosarthur/gita).

[image]

Comment: That shows the first line only (%s), not the whole commit message ("nothing more, nothing less", as the asker wrote). If you have a way of doing show-branch with %B, then that would be helpful.

Answer (score 11):

## Print commit message using git-rev-list

[`git-rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) is the plumbing command that let's you print the message of a commit.

Use it like this.

```
git rev-list --max-count=1 --no-commit-header --format=%B <commit>
```

- [`--max-count=1`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---max-countltnumbergt): we're just interested in one commit
- [`--no-commit-header`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---no-commit-header): Don't show the default commit header
- [`--format=%B`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---formatltformatgt): show message (subject `%s` + `%n%n` + body `%b`)
- `<commit>`: a `sha`, `HEAD`, `branch-name`, `tag-name`, `branch1...branch2` etc.

It's a lot faster than `git log` or `git show`.

Comment: This won't work for merge commits though that have two parents: you'll have to use `tail +3`.

Comment: @leponzo, bummer. Maybe it's better to use some kind of sed magic to get rid of the shas reliably

Comment: newer versions of git (2.33+) have added a  `--no-commit-header` option to rev-list. 
 If you need use sed, you can use `sed '/^commit [0-9a-f]\{40\}$/d'` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68514358/10807837)

Answer (score 3):

I use shortlog for this:

```
$ git shortlog master..
Username (3):
      Write something
      Add something
      Bump to 1.3.8
```

Answer (score 2):

To Get my **Last Commit Message** alone in git

`git log --format=%B -n 1 $(git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h") | cat -`