# Git - how to revert a merge

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-merge, git-rebase, git-revert

I am using Intellij and Git.

I mistakenly merged our `development` branch into our `autoapproval_hierarchy_ui` branch and pushed it to the remote repo. Now I would like to revert that merge.

Please can someone advise how I can do so?

I would like to basically have it exactly like it was before I did the merge, i.e. at 2020/04/06 at 10:35 (ass you can see in the picture below).

[image]

This means it will no longer have the changes from the `development` branch in the `autoapproval_hierarchy_ui` branch on the remote repo.

I have tried to 'Reset Current Branch to Here...',

[image]

and this sets my local workspace in the desired state,

[image]

but I cannot seem to `push` that state to the remote repo.

If I do a:

Git -> Compare with Branch... -> `autoapproval_hierarchy_ui`

There are all the merge differences.

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments from jessehouwing below, I think I can do the following:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61027235/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-with-a-newer-commit-after-it/61029806#61029806

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to revert a merge commit with a newer commit after it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61027235/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-with-a-newer-commit-after-it)

Comment: @jessehouwing,Thanks. I am just having a look an trying to understand it.

Comment: @jessehouwing, please can you look my UPDATE above. Should I do an `Interactive Rebase from Here...`?  (I don't need to keep the history).

Comment: I think you will have to use the revert option, or by-pass the branch protection to do a force-push. Rebase will be the cleaner option, but with branch protection in place, that's not an option.

Comment: Yes, I am scared to do a rebase. I will try do a revert, but I am a bit confused of what exact command to use for my git based on your command: `git revert sha-of-2 -m X`.

Comment: I ended up just creating a new branch from the last commit I want to keep.

Comment: Unless you specifically want an `IntelliJ-idea` solution ( which someone provided below ) this question should be closed as a duplicate; as the answer of how to revert a pushed merge has been asked and answered many times, as pointed at by @jessehouwing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I revert a Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you have **merged unwanted changes** from `development` to `autoapproval_hierarchy_ui`

**Problem:**
I made a test environment where I merged **4 commits** from `dev` to remote `main` [My current Git Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioFJh.png). Now I want to revert `dev` changes from remote `main`!

**Solution:**
Go to your IntelliJ Idea:

1. Understand where `dev` branch collides with `main`. From my [Git Model Examle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBv19.png) Git Model example it is where I have a commit: `Merge pull request #1 from dev`
2. Make a left-click on that collision (now in the right bottom corner appeared a window)
3. Hover over the root directory option and make right-click [Image of this step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abvVL.png)
4. Pick option: `Revert Selected Changes`
5. Pop-up window can appear [Example of a pop-up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59CQ2.png). Select OK
6. Now you have changes that **will** return `main` to the status before `dev` merge. [Before `dev` merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNlAT.png).
7. Now push this changes to remote `main` with the next commands:

`git add .`
`git commit -m "YOUR COMMIT MESSAGE"`
`git push origin main`

> YOUR COMMIT MESSAGE - For example: Reverted last merge

Now you can see that `main` branch got rid of unwanted changes from `dev` branch: [Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVqiT.png)