# Exclude Preceding Commit> line from git rev-list formatting

Tags: git

I'm trying to work on a branch diff command, and I've got it all working... Except for the formatting. I can use `--pretty=oneline` to display just the information I want, except it displays the full hash, and doesn't colorize the output.

So it'd just output this:

```
fa73c05913292fbce940075fc8f454bad5066666 Example Commit Message
de4dbeffa249393dddebb7b13ae555cb97cad5be Another Example Commit Message
```

If I try and do a custom format string, such as this: `--pretty="format:%C(yellow)%h%C(reset) %s"`, it works, but it also displays an additional line above it.

E.g.

```
commit >fa73c05913292fbce940075fc8f454bad5066666
fa73c05 Example Commit Message
commit >de4dbeffa249393dddebb7b13ae555cb97cad5be
de4dbef Another Example Commit Message
```

Is there a way to have `git rev-list` output a format without the preceding `commit >abcdef3...` lines?

Comment: `git rev-list` and `git log` are essentially the same command, except for the output formatting and the fact that `git log` will start from `HEAD` if not given a starting point.  Hence `git log --format=... <additional rev-list arguments>` will do the trick here.

Comment: @torek Ahh, that'll work. I just need to separate the arguments with a `..`, which I'm haivng a surprisingly hard time with. I've managed to get it to `git rev-list branch-name.. | sed -e 1b -e '$!d' |  sed -e "s/\n/../"`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What exactly do you want this "branch diff command" to do anyway?  It may already be provided as one of git's many Swiss-army-chainsaw (with no palm guard) tools...

Comment: @torek Haha, that's definitely an accurate description of git's many tools. And you're completely right. I feel like an idiot that I didn't just do this: `git log --pretty="format:..." branch-name..` Which is literally exactly what I wanted. A list of the commits that differ between branches. Not sure why the hell I was using `rev-list` instead.

Comment: Sounds like you may want `git cherry` and/or the "symmetric difference" set computed by `r1...r2`.  E.g., `git log --oneline --left-right --cherry-mark A...B` (note three dots, see gitrevisions(7)).

Comment: @torek That's probably it. Probably an attempt to mitigate any cockups on my part in terms of not rebasing my feature branch off of the main development branch. But that works perfectly I think. :)

Comment: I must agree with torec here.

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question if you really do want to use `rev-list` and not just `log`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To leave an answer for those who will come next/

@torec mentioned in his comment the following:

> `git rev-list` and `git log` are essentially the same command

The answer is to use the following format:

```
# print out the log history in the desired format.
git log --pretty="format:..." <SHA-1>
```

Answer (score 10):

> If I try and do a custom format string, such as this: `--pretty="format:%C(yellow)%h%C(reset) %s"`, it works, but it also displays an additional line above it.

Actually... With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), "[`git rev-list`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fe3fec53a63a1c186452f61b0e55ac2837bf18a1/Documentation/git-rev-list.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list))</sup> learns to *omit* the `commit <object-name>` header lines from the output with the **`--no-commit-header` option**.

See [commit d1c5ae7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1c5ae78ce1260c94c9e626b83dc0901e6843178) (11 Jul 2021) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fe3fec5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe3fec53a63a1c186452f61b0e55ac2837bf18a1), 22 Jul 2021)</sup>

> #### [`rev-list`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1c5ae78ce1260c94c9e626b83dc0901e6843178): add option for `--pretty=format` *without* header
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>
>
> In general, we encourage users to use plumbing commands, like [`git rev-list`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d1c5ae78ce1260c94c9e626b83dc0901e6843178/Documentation/git-rev-list.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list))</sup>, over porcelain commands, like [`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d1c5ae78ce1260c94c9e626b83dc0901e6843178/Documentation/git-log.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup>, when scripting.
>
> However, `git rev-list` has one glaring problem that prevents it from being used in certain cases: when `--pretty` is used with a custom format, it always prints out a line containing "commit" and the object ID.
>
> This makes it unsuitable for many scripting needs, and forces users to use `git log` instead.
>
> While we can't change this behavior for backwards compatibility, we can add an option to suppress this behavior, so let's do so, and call it "`--no-commit-header`".
> Additionally, add the corresponding positive option to switch it back on.
>
> Note that this option doesn't affect the built-in formats, only custom formats.
> This is exactly the same behavior as users already have from `git log` and is what most users will be used to.

`rev-list-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d1c5ae78ce1260c94c9e626b83dc0901e6843178/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L1067-L1074):

> **`--no-commit-header`**
>
> Suppress the header line containing "commit" and the object ID printed before
> the specified format.  This has no effect on the built-in formats; only custom
> formats are affected.
>
> **`--commit-header`**
>
> Overrides a previous `--no-commit-header`.

Answer (score 7):

There is literally no way to do this, unfortunately. `git rev-list` is implemented [thusly](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8858448bb49332d353febc078ce4a3abcc962efe/builtin/rev-list.c#L113):

```c
    if (revs->abbrev_commit && revs->abbrev)
        fputs(find_unique_abbrev(&commit->object.oid, revs->abbrev),
              stdout);
    else
        fputs(oid_to_hex(&commit->object.oid), stdout);
```

so no matter what options you put in, `git rev-list` will always print some kind of commit hash.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sed` after git rev-list to delete all the lines starting with `commit`.

`git rev-list --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%C(reset) %s" | sed '/^commit [0-9a-f]\{40\}$/d'`.

Comment: Since there is already an accepted answer that is almost 4 years old, what is wrong with it? Since you're posting a new answer that is?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the original accepted answer. That's another way to do it. Stumbled on the question when looking for an answer to the problem and I thought I could add another way to do it. Some people might HAVE to use `git rev-list` instead of `git log` for some reasons.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen the original answer answers a different question