# How do I use git cherry to get committer email?

Tags: git, awk, pipe, git-log, git-cherry

`git cherry` is superior to `git log` for getting the difference between two branches. The problem is that its output is limited.

I'm trying to extract the email address (or user) associated with a commit. Here is what I'm doing.

```
git cherry firstbranch secondbranch | awk '/^+/ {print $2}' | awk '{ system("git show $1"); }'
```

All I get is the details of one commit. Instead of every commit that I do get with:

```
git cherry firstbranch secondbranch | awk '/^+/ {print $2}'
```

Something is going wrong with the second pipe operation.

My question is: **How do I use git cherry to get committer email?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Steven Penny's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41175705/1256452) of piping to `git log --no-walk --stdin` is a correct method, and is required in the most complex cases (complex filtering of selected commit-IDs).

There are a couple of tricks that one can use for *this particular* case though.  If you check the (extensive, albeit confusing) [documentation for `git rev-list`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) you will find the options `--left-right`, `--left-only`, `--right-only`, `--cherry-mark`, `--cherry-pick`, and `--cherry`.

The `--left-right` option works with any symmetric difference, i.e., commits selected by `A...B`, which means "all commits that are on branch `A` *or* branch `B`, excluding any commits that are on *both* branches."  This is how `git cherry` does the first part of its thing: it finds commits that are on the symmetric difference.  However, `git cherry` goes on to *throw out* all the commits that are *"the same"*<sup>1</sup> on both branches, then marks those on one side with `-` and those on the other with `+`.  The `--left-right` option marks all commits as either `<` (left side) or `>` (right side).

Since `rev-list` is the Swiss Army Chainsaw command, it *also* has the ability to throw out commits that are the same.  It has even more abilities too: it can throw out commits on one side entirely, same-or-different.  This is what we want in this case: throw out "commits that are the same" (so that we keep only "different" ones), then throw out all "left side" commits (so that we keep only those that are in the right side but not the left).  We get the former with `--cherry-pick`: it keeps only commits that are considered "different".  Then we add `--right-only` to keep only those on the right side, i.e., when we say `firstbranch...secondbranch`, keep only those that are both different *and* in `secondbranch` ... which is exactly what `git cherry` does.

Hence:

```
git rev-list --right-only --cherry-pick firstbranch...secondbranch
```

produces the same commit ID list as:

```
git cherry firstbranch secondbranch
```

(with the single difference being that instead of `+ face0ff...`, it prints `+face0ff`, i.e., no space after the `+` mark).

This seems pretty silly: instead of just the four words `git cherry` and two branch names, we need `git rev-list` and a bunch of options and two branch names and three periods.  We've typed in lots more letters to get pretty much the same thing.  So we could just use the shorter command and pipe it to `git log`, but now we get to the tricky bit.

#### `git log` and `git rev-list` are very nearly the same command

In fact, they are built from the same source code, they just set some internal options differently (and `git log` will pretend you said `HEAD` if you don't name any other starting points).  Since we're about to pipe the output of `git rev-list` to `git log --pretty='%h %ce'`, maybe we can just do the whole thing in `git log` directly.

Sure enough, we can.  We need all those same options as with `git rev-list`, but now we can just run:

```
git log --cherry-pick --right-only --pretty='%h %ce' firstbranch...secondbranch
```

(you may want `--no-merges` here as well—I'm not sure offhand what `git cherry` does about merges!).

---

<sup>1</sup>"Sameness", in this case, is determined by the output of `git patch-id`, which basically strips identifying line numbers off diffs (and also strips certain white space details).  Thus, if one commit was cherry-picked into another branch, both such commits will usually have the same patch-ID.  (The patch-IDs will differ if someone had to resolve merge conflicts.)

Comment: aha - the key point I was wondering about was what `git cherry` does about merges. I'll go find that out.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
git cherry firstbranch secondbranch | awk '$0=$2' | git log --no-walk --stdin --pretty='%h %ce'
```

1. --no-walk: only show the given commits, but do not traverse their ancestors
2. %h: abbreviated commit hash
3. %ce: committer email

[Source](//webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:oV92GURT0X8J:kernel.org)

Comment: @torek true, except `rev-list` does this stupid crap http://stackoverflow.com/q/36927089

Comment: Thanks @torek - can you please expand that into an answer? I can't quite work out what you mean - and it might be a better answer.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean to use `--format` in `git rev-list` here, just that you can use `git rev-list` itself instead of `git cherry`. Since rev-list and log are basically the same command, you can also do all of this right inside `git log`, for this particular case. For more complex cases (where you want a `sed` or `awk` selection) you still need `--stdin --no-walk`.

Comment: @StevenPenny: oh, sorry, it *is* `$0=$2`, I was thinking of that as `$0==$2` which would skip everything!