# Do *not* show pgp signature in git log

Tags: bash, git

The `git log` subcommand has the option `--show-signature` to display pgp signatures of the commits (if present).
This can also be enabled by default via `git config log.showSignature true`.

I have set this config option to true.
The problem is that I am now looking for an option to pass to `git log` to *not* show the signature in the log (while the config is still set to true),
something like
`git config --no-show-signature`.

I was unable to find anything helpful in the git documentation.
For context: Most of the time, I do want `git log` to be active, but in some automated scripts, I really don't need this, because it messes up some automatic parsing etc.

Comment: Try `git -c log.showSignature=false log`. See [`git -c`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt).

Comment: I think it would be worth discussing at a `git` mailing-list and or opening an issue asking for an optional boolean argument to `git log --show-signature`. Something could serve to negate all option switches like: `git log --show-signature[=][true|false]` or a `no-` negation prefix, as you mentioned: `git log --[no-]show-signature`.

Comment: Ideally, `git log` should grow a `--porcelain` flag that makes it ignore *all* user configuration, so that one can use `git log` reliably in scripts. But that's a much bigger chunk of work than just adding `--no-show-signature`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll repeat @phd's comment, which in the current state of things seems like the most straightforward way to cancel that config parameter (and only that one) :

> Try `git -c log.showSignature=false log`

---

Another option is to use `git log`'s sister command : `git rev-list`.

The differences are :

- `git rev-list` isn't affected by `log.*` config parameters
- you need to add `--no-commit-header` to avoid one extra line on each commit (see [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68514358/86072) which links to [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---no-commit-header))
- you need to specify explicitly the refs/branches names (e.g: `git rev-list` will error, you need to say `git rev-list HEAD`)

Other than that, it understands the same options as `git log` :

```
git rev-list --no-commit-header --graph --format="%h (%an %ad) %s" HEAD
```