# Git get message of a commit with specific .git folder

Tags: git, command-line, .git-folder

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3357357/248616) we can get commit message of a given revision via command

```
$ git log --format=%B -n 1 $revNum
```

Though this command requires we are **inside** the git repo folder i.e. somewhere below folder containing `.git` folder. That requires us to [pushd and popd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3357357/248616) to go in and out of the .git folder every time we want to call the command (from external working directory).

I'm looking for params of `git log` command that help to specify .git folder like that. Please share as you know the ones.

p.s.

My google found me [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386291/git-git-dir-not-working-as-expected) though adding `--git-dir=$myCode/.git --work-tree=$myCode` not working for `git log` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `-C` [option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20115678/248616) for that. But keep in mind that you need to add the `-C` option **before the git command you want to use** (`log`, `status`, ...).

For example:

```
git -C ~/src/docker log
```

But the following **will not work**:

```
git log -C ~/src/docker
```

You can also use `--git-dir`, but you cannot use you shell capabilities of [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) in that case and you need to use the full path (no `*`, `~`, etc.):

```
git --git-dir=/home/nam/src/docker/.git log
```

Comment: Ah, the -C param of `git` command that works. I focus so much on `git log`