# Gitlab-CI Environment Variable for Commit Comment

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm currently using GitLab-CI to CD my project's staging branch to Google Firebase.
Each deployment gets a special comment with the PipelineID and Build ID.

```
firebase deploy -m "Pipeline $CI_PIPELINE_ID, build $CI_BUILD_ID" --non-interactive --token $FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY
```

For ease of use, when rolling back commits in the Firebase console, I'd like to include the commit message into the deploy comment.

I searched through the documentation and didn't find a variable for that. Am I mistaken, or is that really not possible?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Gitlab 10.8 and newer:**

The `$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE` environment variable contains the commit message. Thanks to Ladislav for the update!

**Original answer (before gitlab 10.8):**

It's definitely not possible through predefined Gitlab CI variables as this [list](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/#predefined-variables-environment-variables) shows. But you may be able to do it some other way.

For instance you could retrieve the commit message using the following (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3357357/6654146))

```
git rev-list --format=%B --max-count=1 HEAD
```

or

```
git rev-list --format=%B --max-count=1 $CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

And then use the output of that command in your own command.

For instance:

```
MESSAGE=$(git rev-list --format=%B --max-count=1 HEAD)
firebase deploy -m "Pipeline $CI_PIPELINE_ID, build $CI_BUILD_ID, message $MESSAGE" --non-interactive --token $FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY
```

Comment: It is now available in Gitlab 10.8 as `$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE` environment variable: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/#predefined-variables-environment-variables