# How can I retrieve/save the commit message of a file in Git?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

What I want to do is save the commit message (as text) of some files from a repo in a .txt file.
Are there any commands that can help me achieve this? I need to parse these commit messages and use them in another place.

I have searched everywhere on the internet but I have found nothing useful.

[Basically, I want to save this in a text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze3UL.png)

Thank-you in advance...

Comment: if you are using git from bash, you could try redirecting: `git log --oneline somefile.txt > log.txt`.... or with blame `git blame somefile.txt > blame.txt`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701404/list-all-commits-for-a-specific-file, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357280/print-commit-message-of-a-given-commit-in-git and send that output to a file. Read [ask] and show what you have tried. It is impossible that you searched the entire internet and found nothing. Do show what you did find.